# how does ORM map to interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am learning JPA Projections these days!
There is something strange that I can't understand.

the follow is my question

Spring Data JPA Repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Serializable> {

  Collection<NameAgeOnly> findByAgeGreaterThan(int age);
}
```

Interface(there is no Clazz which implement this interface)

```
public interface NameAgeOnly {
  String getName();

  String getAge();
}
```

RepositoryTest

```
public class RepositoryTest {
  List<CountByAddress> countByAddressList = personRepository.getCityNameAndPersonCount();
  debug.log(countByAddressList.get(0).getName());
}
```

How can **countByAddressList.get(0).getName** can work? there is no class which implements NameAgeOnly?

Is there any default class for Interface? 
Anyone who can explain How to ORM map to Interface Not Class?

thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) explains it:

> The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface at runtime for each element returned and forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object.

Comment: Thanks :)
I already read it.
I want to know that How query engine force to forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object
Where can I find it?  
And Can I see the proxy instance?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. spring-data is opensource, so you can browse the source code. You can also print the returned instances, or inspect them with your debugger. You can also google for "what is a dynamic proxy".